# java print method, a format method confusion of the string class

Tags: java, string-formatting

I am not sure how to interpret the format method down below of the String class,ugh so confused, could someone help me with me recognize it so i can use it.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String[] s = new String[] { "quit", "add", "delete", "find", "change" };
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("| %d:%s |", i, s[i]));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("| %d:%s |", i, s[i]));
        }
```

%d is a placeholder for numbers you just place it where you want to use your number.
%s is a placeholder for a string.

```
String.format("| %d:%s |", i, s[i])
```

first run string looks like this 
"| 0:quit|"
each time you loop you just go trought array of strings s. And decimal is used for showing its location in array.

Formating string can be very usefull and it make your strings rather more elegant and easyer to read :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `%d` represents a placeholder of numbers (*"Formats the argument as a decimal integer"*) and `%s` is a placeholder for `String`

The command will supplement for the value of `i` where `%d` is and `s[i]` for where `%s` is...

Check out [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more details

You could also check out [How to format String in Java – String format Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html) which goes into more detail